# Excel: How to use Range references in formulas instead of Defined Names?

Tags: excel, reference, excel-formula

I will give an example:
I have cell A1, named as "First_Cell" in the Name Manager. When I use a formula, for example:

```
=IF(A1=A2, "Equal", "Not Equal")
```

When creating the formula, if I CLICK on A1, the formula becomes:

```
=IF(First_Cell=A2, "Equal", "Not Equal")
```

How can I use the formula, clicking on A1, but INSTEAD of having the Name Manager name, still have A1?

I want to do the exact opposite of what it is explained in the following article:
[Define and use names in formulas](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/Define-and-use-names-in-formulas-4d0f13ac-53b7-422e-afd2-abd7ff379c64)

Comment: The only way would be to delete the named ranges.

Comment: I come across this situation when I need to copy/drag the formula. instead of clicking `A1`, you need to type 'A1' in the formula then it stays A1

Comment: Note that names can have relative rather than absolute references, so that formulas which contain them update their references when copied  or dragged.

Comment: Also, you can *type* A1 in the formula (rather than click on the cell) and the name won't be automatically applied.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `INDIRECT` will help. I'm not sure if you insist on **clicking** on the cells instead of writing their reference value, but you can press **F3** and paste a list of all named rages with their reference, and than use `INDIRECT`to use the reference instead of the name:
[image: Using INDIRECT function]